# I'm done with the class the today Vs. I finished the class today

Tags: meaning-in-context

In standard English, which of the following two means that I finished the class today only but doesn't mean that I finish it forever?

> I **am done** with the /my class (or lesson).

or

> I **finished** the class (or lesson).

In both cases I mean for today only, but I'm not sure if one of them correct in this context or both of them are just a matter of style.

Comment: Maybe, *I finished my today's class* or *I'm done with my today's class*.

Comment: "done with" can also be used to indicate that you are giving up on something. For example: "I am done with her bad behavior. I don't plan to see her again."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifying that it's only done *today*, you should put that into the sentence.

You could say one of the following:

> I finished my class **for today**.
>   I finished **today's** class.

Or:

> I'm done with my class **for today**.
>   I'm done with **today's** class.

---

However, most people will understand this by context.

The following conversation could be heard at the end of the day:

> "Are your classes done?"
>   "Yes, I just finished them."

If it's still the middle of a term, it's assumed that the conversation is talking about their daily classes.

But if the same conversation were heard at the end of the term, when final exams are being written and classes are actually wrapping up, then it would be assumed to be not about daily classes but about them being done for good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  What about the using of 'to be done with' in this context?

Comment: @Conceivableassessment Yes, you can use that verb too. *I'm done with my class for today* and *I'm done today's classes*. The main point is the use of *today*.